# Checking descendants of parent from a HashSet of values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a HashSet with xml child nodes I want to retrieve.  I am using the following linq (not working) to try to get all childs and return parent also:

xml:

```
<team>
    <bob>a</bob>
    <mary>b</mary>
    <joe>c</joe>
</team>
<team>
    <john>d</john>
</team>
```

HashSet:

```
HashSet<string> people = new HashSet<string> { "mary", "joe", "john" };
```

LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from d in doc.Descendants("team")
                               where people.Contains(d.Descendants().Name.LocalName)
                               select d;
```

Should Return:

```
<team>
    <mary>b</mary>
    <joe>c</joe>
</team>
<team>
    <john>d</john>
</team>
```

But its not working.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update #1**

I am adding a complete example, which returns nothing:

```
public void test1()
        {
            var xml =
                     @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                       <hereistheroot>
                           <team>
                               <bob>a</bob>
                               <mary>b</mary>
                               <joe>c</joe>
                           </team>
                           <team>
                               <john>d</john>
                           </team>
                       </hereistheroot>";
            XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

            HashSet<string> people = new HashSet<string> { "mary", "joe", "john" };

            IEnumerable<XElement> result = from d in doc.Descendants("team")
                                           where people.Contains(d.Name.LocalName)
                                           select d;

        }
```

It returns nothing. It should return two XElement objects:

First one:

```
<team>
    <mary>b</mary>
    <joe>c</joe>
</team>
```

Second One:

```
<team>
    <john>d</john>
</team>
```

**Note**: For testing, remove the "Where" clause in the linq and it will correctly return the two XElement objects but that is the main problem: I need to get the "Where" clause to allow me to pick people based on the HashSet.  Thanks.

Comment: So what's the result instead? Also above XML isn't valid XML, since no closing tags on the name nodes are given. (`<bob />` instead of `<bob>`). There also seems to be more than one root element in the XML, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Max, thanks, it has been corrected.  There is no result, there is an error on d.Descendants().Name.LocalName.

Comment: The LINQ query `from d in doc.Elements("team").Descendants() where people.Contains(d.Name.LocalName) select d;` returns the nodes `<mary>b</mary><joe>c</joe> <john>d</john>`, but it seems you want a result set of two `<team>` nodes with modified members? Or is that what you want, a result set of 3 nodes? You can access the parents of these 3 nodes in code anytime you want, too.

Comment: Max, thanks for your input. The problem is that it needs to return two <team> nodes as shown in the above "Should Return" example.  It cannot combine them.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to differentiate which team node provided the descendent. As Max says, you may access the nodes parent at any time. So add an attribute to define the team nodes and check d.Parent.Attribute for the value.

Comment: Thanks but that will not work.  I cannot modify the xml.

Comment: Please see "Update #1" and the "Note" at the end for a complete example.  Thanks.

Comment: you can make it much easier by just using a loop and deleting the extra descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are actually trying to accomplish two different things here:

1. Identify all the top-level `team` elements that contain child nodes having the names in your set.
2. Construct a new XML DOM that contains only those top-level `team` elements, and in those elements have only those child nodes having the names in your set.

If that's correct, then the following will accomplish that:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from d in doc.Descendants("team")
                               let validDescendants = d.Descendants()
                                   .Where(c => people.Contains(c.Name.LocalName)).ToArray()
                               where validDescendants.Length > 0
                               select new XElement(d.Name, validDescendants);
```

An alternative equivalent of the above, using more of the query expression syntax (i.e. to initialize `validDescendants`):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from d in doc.Descendants("team")
                               let validDescendants =
                                    (from c in d.Descendants()
                                     where people.Contains(c.Name.LocalName)
                                     select c).ToArray()
                               where validDescendants.Length > 0
                               select new XElement(d.Name, validDescendants);
```

Note that this approach leaves the original `doc` tree unchanged, returning instead an enumeration of entirely new `team` elements having the configuration you desire.

If you'd rather just keep that `doc` tree and remove the child elements from the returned `team` elements, you could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from d in doc.Descendants("team")
                               where d.Descendants()
                                   .Any(c => people.Contains(c.Name.LocalName))
                               select d;

foreach (XElement element in result)
{
    foreach (XElement child in element.Descendants().ToList())
    {
        if (!people.Contains(child.Name.LocalName))
        {
            child.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in that example, it will leave untouched any `team` elements that *didn't* include at least one element having a name in your set. That's fixable too, of course, but since you seem to only want to retrieve elements that would be non-empty after your filtering, I'm assuming the first example above is more along the lines of what you want. I showed the second only as a variation, for you to build on if you have something more specific in mind that you haven't described fully in your question.

Comment: Peter, thank you, that works awesome! Quick question for my own knowledge (and since I have been breaking my head).  How would I convert the above first example to Query Expression Syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Peter, thanks that was exactly what I was looking for.  Much appreciated.